# Why plant tissues end in -enchyma?

Tags: botany, terminology, plant-anatomy, etymology

Many plant tissue types end in the affix ***-enchyma***.

- [Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/parenchyma): *enkhyma* "infusion," from *en-* "in" + *khein* "to pour"

Examples are **parenchyma**, **collenchyma**, and **sclerenchyma**.

- (meaning "to pour beside," "glue infusion," and "hard infusion.")

My question: **Where did this usage of -enchyma meaning "infusion" for plant tissues come from?**

- I'm curious from a biological more so than a historical perspective. I.e., *why* was this word choice chosen for plant tissues?

The best explanation I've found is from [Plant Systematics](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ia2eIPVksMMC&pg=PA413&ved=2ahUKEwjp2r3BvP_dAhXRqlkKHQ0tDNYQ6AEwCHoECAIQAQ) by Michael Simpson:

> *Para*, beside + *en-chein*, to pour; **in reference to the analogy that parenchyma is poured beside other tissues to fill up space**.

- So far I haven't been able to corroborate this or expand upon it...

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenchyma), `Originally, Erasistratus and other anatomists used [parenchyma] to refer to certain human tissues. Later, it was also applied to plant tissues by Nehemiah Grew.` so perhaps further investigation from a human anatomy perspective will be informative

Comment: I'm also interested to learn more about the difference between the Greek roots for chyme vs -chyma (khūlos vs khéō) and how their origins inform this question further...